# How to prevent a UIViewController from being popped out?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a childViewController which is pushed from parentViewController. In childViewController I want to block pop action in a particular condition.

I wrote this code in viewWillDisappear: But I guess need to do this somewhere else.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if changesMade {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Changes made are not saved. Do you wish to save changes made?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        let saveOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            self.saveSession()
        })

        alertController.addAction(saveOption)
        alertController.addAction(cancelOption)
        present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just guess(Not sure) try super.viewWillDisappear(animated) after your code because when your view goes to disapperar all values go to deinit. as per my guess

Comment: Why don't you check if changes were made just before trying to pop the view controller.
`if changesMade {
  showAlert()
} else {
  dismissVC()
}`

Comment: if you know when to block pop action, immediately hide back button or disable it so user wan't be able to perform action and it wan't pop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases here:

1. User can pop using back button.
2. User can pop using interactive pop gesture of navigation controller.

I think you should use a custom back button and name it **Done** and write your logic of showing alert on press of this button. 
Using the custom back button would disable the interactive pop gesture by default and you will be spared from playing the dance of enabling/disabling interactivePopGesture on navigation controller.

Comment: I think this is a good way to go. But there is one more twist, that I am not using navigation controller's navbar. I have my own custom navbar. So how do i go ahead.

Comment: If you have created a custom NavigationBar(a subclass of UINavigationBar), I don't think it changes anything. UINavigationBar class has a back button item which you need to change to custom done button.

Comment: My custom navbar is subclass of UIView

Comment: I guess I need to disable and enable interactivePopGesture

Comment: Yeah this is what you need to do in this case. By the way, any specific reason of not subclassing UINavigationBar?

Comment: I did not get flexibility to customize navbar

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a very simple solution: `navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` - this will hide "BACK" button and disable swipe-to-back feature.

Answer (score 1):

block pop action till your changes are not saved like this

```
if changesMade {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Changes made are not saved. Do you wish to save changes made?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        let saveOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            self.saveSession()
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })

        alertController.addAction(saveOption)
        alertController.addAction(cancelOption)
        present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
```

Update - Add this below custom button and its action in child View controller which is being pushed from parent View Controller 
so, without satisfying your condition user can not move from child to parent again

For customising action of navigation backButton you need to manually add a back Button using below line , you can Customise barButton being added here in DidLoad

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.backToInitial(sender:)))
```

It will perform required Action

```
 @objc func backToInitial(sender: AnyObject) {
        if changesMade {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Changes made are not saved. Do you wish to save changes made?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let cancelOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
            let saveOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                self.saveSession()
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            })

            alertController.addAction(saveOption)
            alertController.addAction(cancelOption)
            present(alertController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

and I do not think you can stop default back button action task of navigation Controller as it is designed the way to perform it

But yes you can manage it in ViewWillDisappear as :

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if self.isMovingFromParentViewController || self.isBeingDismissed {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false) //here task but will not result as Expected output 
        }
    }
```

-----------------Re-Update ---------------

in swift I used a objective-C class to get output as expected now, childViewController pop action is being controller from a alert using default back button that we get from navigation controller

You can customise you pop action to perform or not until your condition is not satisfied
Github Link - https://github.com/RockinGarg/NavigationBackButton.git

Comment: How do I block the pop action? Pop action is triggered in two ways either you click the back button or through gesture.

Comment: are you saying about back button of navigation controller that come by default you want a check there ? in gesture action you can write my answered code directly as till the values are not stored pop will not be performed

Comment: updated my answer , Pease check, hope it helps you. you need to use a custom back button here to block pop action I wrote code for it too

Comment: Since child view controller was pushed from parent view controller. By default, user can swipe from left and go back to the parent view controller right? What do i do to prevent that?

Comment: pushed using a navigation controller ? or how please let me know the line for pushing to childViewController

Comment: let editVC = EditVC()
navigationController?.pushViewController(editVC, animated: true)

Comment: Navigation controller dont allow swipe gesture to be added when pushing a viewCotntroller it adds a back button by default in NavBar that is used to swipe between screens for this I had updated my answer with adding custom back button and its action, so just in childViewController add the custom button code with its action and problem will be solved

Comment: Check my updated answer with a sample code I think this is what you actually desire

Comment: Hey i downloaded your project from GitHub, Pop does not show when I swipe in CheckVC. Pop up is only shown while clicking the back button.

Comment: so when you are looking it to appear ? you wrote to control at self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) this time , this will occur when we press back button

Comment: Upvote for the github link. Saved me hours of headache.

Answer (score -1):

I found a much more elegant solution (in my opinion).

It works no matter how the user triggers the pop (accessibility escape, swipe back gesture, tapping back) since it overrides the built in pop methods that the system uses.

## Swift 5

```
public class DiscardSafeNavigationController:UINavigationController {
    /// Should the pop be prevented? Set this to `true` when you have changes which need to be protected
    public var hasUnsavedChanges:Bool = false

    /// Show a prompt on the top most screen asking the user if they wish to proceed with the pop
    /// - Parameter discardCallback: The callback to use if the user opts to discard
    private func confirmDiscardChanges(discardCallback:@escaping (()->())) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Discard changes", message: "Are you sure you want to discard any unsaved changes?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Discard", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: { (_) in
            discardCallback()
            //User elected to discard and so, at this point, they no longer have changes to save
            self.hasUnsavedChanges = false
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
        self.topViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        //If there aren't unsaved changes, popping is safe
        if !hasUnsavedChanges {
            return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
        }else {
            //Changes have been made. Block the pop and first check with the user before continuing
            confirmDiscardChanges {
                super.popViewController(animated: animated)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }


}
```

and when you want to enable discard protection from any child view controllers, simply use:

`(self.navigationController as? DiscardSafeNavigationController)?.hasUnsavedChanges = true`

and then any time the navigation controller is asked to pop it, the navigation controller will ask the user first.

Comment: the reference to self.hasUnsavedChanges is undefined. Where did you put this var?

Comment: Whoops, missed a line. Just define it as a class var of `DiscardSafeNavigationController`. I'll edit it.

Comment: This doesn't work. Unfortunately returning nil just messes up the navigation. The previous view controller is still loaded, and any custom logic in that VC to customize the navigationBar will execute and show the previous navigation items, keeping the previous view so everything gets really jenky.

Comment: What exactly are you doing that the *previous* view controller is loading when you refuse to return a reference to it? I very carefully tested this and use it in production and don't have the issue you're facing

Comment: Well I may be mistaken, however the nav bar goes back to the root nav bar even though the pushed view controller does not pop. This is what happens when returning nil.